# How to let jQuery multiple addClass works in my preferred order?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tlist td div').click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('first').addClass('second').addClass('third');                 
    });
});
```

I want to do `addClass('first')` first, then `addClass('second')` second and the last `addClass('third')`, but they are always triggered at the same, how can I do?

Comment: `addClass()` is a synchronous operation, so it doesn't have a callback. Why do you need it to be in order? Does it have to happen after some time between each other?

Comment: I need them in order because of CSS effects. Do you have some alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` to ensure that the next class is added only after the previous one has been rendered in DOM. But it does look a little ugly though. Of course, you could fine-tune the delay as per your needs. Here's how it would be:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#someDiv').click(function() {

    $(this).addClass('first');
    
     setTimeout(function(element) {
        element.addClass('second');
        
        setTimeout(function() {
          element.addClass('third');
        },1, $(this));
     },1, $(this));
  });
});
```

```css
.first:after {
  content: 'First';
}

.second:after {
  content: 'Second';
}


.third:after {
  content: 'Third';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="someDiv">
 Click me!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine and simple

```
$(this).addClass('first second third');
```